# How to show both hamburger icon and app icon in actionbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, hamburger-menu

I wish to show both the dynamic hamburger icon from ActionBarDrawerToggle as well as the app icon before the title in a navigation drawer setup. Something like this:

[image]

If this info is of any use, I have an abstract base drawer activity which other activities are extending, to get an activity per screen from the navigation menu - mainly to avoid all the problems encountered in nested fragments when a viewpager comes in.

I've tried using a custom view in the toolbar like this:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in my DrawerLayout xml. Also tried ImageView followed by TextView. Also negative margins. Each of them gives something like this:

[image]

**How can I decrease the space between the hamburger icon and the app icon?**
Below is the method I'm calling from each child activity's onCreate to initialise the stuff.

```
    protected void inflateActivityViewInFrame(int layoutId, int titleStringId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, mFrameLayout, false);
        mFrameLayout.addView(view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(titleStringId);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }
```

---

I also tried the following combination:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in the DrawerLayout in the xml and the following code for initialisation:

```
    protected void inflateActivityViewInFrame(int layoutId, int titleStringId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutId, mFrameLayout, false);
        mFrameLayout.addView(view);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            };
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
        toolbar.setTitle(titleStringId);
    }
```

This one doesn't show the app logo, even though setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true) is used.
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How do I display both the menu icon and the app logo with the correct spacing?

Comment: Also tried setLogo() in toolbar along with actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true), still the same.

Also, removing the title to get normal toolbar in the layout, setting title on toolbar using toolbar.setTitle() and actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); in that order, again the spacing is screwed up.

Comment: Have also tried 
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp" in the toolbar attributes to no avail. Please help :(

Comment: have you solved the issue?

Comment: @dit nope, I moved on to bottom navigation view pattern. Pls comment/answer if you find a solution :)

Comment: Refer this link. I think you get solution here.  
       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40717684/how-to-reduce-the-gap-between-navigation-icon-and-toolbar-title