# How to reduce the gap between navigation icon and toolbar title?

Tags: android, android-layout, text, android-support-library, android-toolbar

My problem is the extra space between the nav-drawer icon and toolbar title. The sample images are below:

[image: spacing between nav-drawer icon and title]

[image: spacing between back icon and toolbar]

The xml view of the toolbar is

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

I have tried to solve this problem by using code below but no change occurred.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //toolbar.setTitleMarginStart(0);
    toolbar.setTitleMarginStart(-8);
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: you can create a custom action bar and display the items as you like.

Comment: Why is this a problem? This is a design decision by the platform developers, and this is how Google's apps for Android look.

Comment: @egor Sometimes the title will be longer and it can give a better look and meaning if we can show 2/3 letters more. Plus experimenting on small things is fun too.

Comment: I agree with @Egor

Comment: I'd say you'll get better UX if you keep titles short, rather then tweaking default system UI. However, I can agree with the perspective that each app is unique: test your UI with your users, and if they react well to this kind of tweaks and find longer titles useful - then this would be the way to go.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Add

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

to the `ToolBar`.

**Complete Code :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Comment: @Sagar Chapagain glad to know that.

Comment: It is nice solution. really helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47207491/remove-padding-between-hamburger-icon-and-toolbar ..Still i am getting gap.!   
@Sagar Chapagain

Comment: In my case i didn't use toolbar like this what should i do? Is there any way is there to change programmatically.

Answer (score 11):

With the `MaterialToolbar` and the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` you can use these attributes:

- **`contentInsetStartWithNavigation`**: Minimum inset for content views within a bar when a navigation button is present, such as the Up button (default value=`72dp`).
- **`contentInsetStart`**: Minimum inset for content views within a bar. Navigation buttons and menu views are excepted (default value = `16dp`)
- **`titleMarginStart`**: specifies extra space on the start side of the toolbar's title. If both this attribute and `titleMargin` are specified, then this attribute takes precedence. Margin values should be positive.

Just use in your layout:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
        ..>
```

Default:
[image]

With `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`:
[image]

With `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` and `app:titleMarginStart="0dp"`:
[image]

You can also define a custom style:

```
<style name="MyToolbar" parent="....">
    <item name="titleMarginStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStart">..dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">..dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"` in toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Add this line app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/share"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/action_back"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="@{title}"
                android:background="4855b5"
                app:titleTextColor="ffffff"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To do In Flutter Android use **titleSpacing: 0,** in ** App Bar** layout

** Sample Code **

```
appBar: AppBar(
    actions: <Widget>[
      Icon(Icons.search_rounded),
      Icon(Icons.notifications),
      Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
    ],
    leadingWidth: 26,
    titleSpacing: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
    leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
    elevation: 100.0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        appbarIcon,
      ],
    ),
  )
```