# Remove Padding between hamburger icon and toolbar.?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar

I am getting a gap between toolbar and hamburger icon.Even i have added **app:contentInsetLeft**,**app:contentInsetStart**,        **app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation** ,still i am getting the gap.

I added the following code to toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#fff">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hi, Ajay Jayendran"
                    android:textColor="#123"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Good Morning"
                    android:textColor="#111"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I using own hamburger icon for navigation drawer. for that, I used following code,

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.navigation_icon);
```

Here, this is a screenshot that gap between icon and toolbar

[image]

Does anybody know how to reduce this space between hamburger icon and toolbar.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## try this it was helpful for you

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
            android:weightSum="1"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_toolBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/_60sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/toolBar_textSize"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_cartLayout"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/cart_bg">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/iv_cart"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/shop_cart" />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_5sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cart_redbox">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvCartItems"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:text="0"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/textSize_11sp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/rl_layoutSetting_Back"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/cart_bg"
                    android:visibility="gone">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_25sp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_25sp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/back_icon">

                    </RelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),   R.drawable.top_left_icon,this.getTheme());
        toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    isDrawerFromHome=false;
                } else {
                    isDrawerFromHome=true;
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }
            }
        });
        toggle.syncState();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code now you can use this xml and you can see in image:-

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hi, Ajay Jayendran"
                android:textColor="#123"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Good Morning"
                android:textColor="#111"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_title"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

and in java : -

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
       findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
           R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

[image]